# Как реализовать контент на определенную ширину

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

http://jsfiddle.net/xLj77yg9/

Подскажите возможно ли чтобы для следующего кода, чтобы контентная область занимала, например 500 пикселей по центру, но при этом на половину изображения был наложен полупрозрачный слой, который тянеться на 50% изображения.

Как вариант можно в фотошопе с изображением поработать. но хотелось бы это реализовать на css

[как необходимо](http://fotki.yandex.ru/next/users/soledar06081984/album/373178/view/1114690)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так? http://jsfiddle.net/5pfbqgcz/